# Is it possible to show default layout in error pages?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

I want to style my app from scratch so I've created a brand new layout and assigned it as default:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
    );

    public function beforeRender() {
        parent::beforeRender();

        $this->layout = 'app';
    }
}
```

However, it seems that it also affects the internal error pages generated by CakePHP that I need for development:

[image: Actual]

Is there a way to make such pages use `app\View\Layouts\default.ctp` instead of `app.ctp`?

[image: Intended]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom exception renderer:-

```
// app/Lib/Error/AppExceptionRenderer.php
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {

    public function render() {
        $this->controller->layout = 'default';
        parent::render();
    }

}
```

Then in app/Config/core.php make sure you tell Cake to use your `AppExceptionRenderer` class for handling exceptions:-

```
Configure::write('Exception', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
    'renderer' => 'AppExceptionRenderer',
    'log' => true
));
```

Using a custom exception renderer gives you greater flexibility over how you handle exceptions in your app.

Finally, move the custom layout definition from `\AppController::beforeRender` to `\AppController::beforeFilter` so it runs earlier and can be overridden in case of error:

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->layout = 'app';
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `\ExceptionRenderer::beforeFilter` callback. There's `\ExceptionRenderer::render` but it doesn't have any `layout` property. Furthermore, `\AppController::beforeRender` gets called *later*... :-?

Comment: Sorry @ÁlvaroGonzález my mistake, you can access the controller from the `render` method and set the layout that way. I've updated my answer to show this.

Comment: Thank you. That changes the layout back to `default` successfully, but afterwards `\AppController::beforeRender` sets it again to `app` (remember I need to set `default` back because I'm modifying it). Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: I mean, I could possibly add a `$do_not_modify_layout` flag but I'm trying to avoid ugly hacks when builtin solutions exist.

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit. Is there a reason why you are forcing all views to use a different layout in `beforeRender`? Would this not be better done in the `beforeFilter`, that way you can easily override it later in specific actions. Using a hack like `$do_not_modify_layout` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: That was the last bit, thank you very much! I've incorporated it into the answer.